# jQuery: Show several elements at once

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Is there a function like this:

```
$.show('#anID, .aClass, .anotherClass, #anotherID');
```

I don't want to write each time

```
$('#anID').show();
$('.aClass').show();
// etc...
```

Comment: `$('#anID, .aClass, .anotherClass, #anotherID').show()`

Comment: Instead add a common class and call it.

Comment: thank you, I had a blackout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the selector and function mixed up:

```
$('#anID, .aClass, .anotherClass, #anotherID').show();
```